# An alternative way of writing Pig Latin Program in Python

Tags: python

I am revisiting a B-Language translation program example in Python from Stanford's notes. This program works where words are transformed such that every vowel cluster is reduplicated with a leading "b".

For example:

- translate("quick")  => "quibuick"
- translate("spaghetti") => "spabaghebettibi"

The code below works perfectly fine, but due to confusion, I was wondering if there's an alternative way to compute the translate(word, separator="b") function which converts a word string by reduplicating each vowel cluster with a leading b. Is it possible to find out a way which exclude the usage of the computation "start = -1"?

```
def translate(word, separator="b"):
   start = -1
   translation = ""
   for i in range(len(word)):
      ch = word[i]
      if isEnglishVowel(ch):
         if start == -1:
            start = i
      else:
         if start >= 0:
            translation += word[start:i] + separator + word[start:i]
            start = -1
         translation += ch
   if start >= 0:
      translation += word[start:] + separator + word[start:]
   return translation

def isEnglishVowel(ch):
   return len(ch) == 1 and "aeiou".find(ch) >= 0

def TestTranslate():
   while True:
      word = input("Enter a single word [or hit enter to quit]: ");
      if word == "": break
      translation = translate(word)
      print("\"{}\" -> \"{}\"".format(word, translation))

if __name__ == "__main__":
   TestTranslate()
```

Thank you.

Comment: You could do this as a one-liner using regular expressions - substitute `([aeiou]+)` (consecutive vowels, as many as possible, as a capturing group) with `\1b\1` (two copies of that group, with a 'b' in between).

Comment: Thanks for the solution but I'm not quite sure how am I supposed to do it. i'm not sure how this can help eliminate the usage of the "start = -1" variable. Would you mind elaborating? @jasonharper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified the code a bit. It uses `vowels` instead of `start` but the internal logic is a little more simplified. Basically grow `vowels` until you encounter a consonant, then pop `vowels` into the translation string with the separator in between.

```
def translate(word, separator="b"):
    translation = ""
    vowels = ""
    for ch in word:
        if vowels and not isEnglishVowel(ch):
            translation += separator + vowels
            vowels = ""
        translation += ch
        if isEnglishVowel(ch):
            vowels += ch
    return translation + separator + vowels if vowels else translation


def isEnglishVowel(ch):
    return len(ch) == 1 and ch in 'aeiou'


def TestTranslate():
    while True:
        word = input("Enter a single word [or hit enter to quit]: ")
        if word == "": break
        translation = translate(word)
        print("\"{}\" -> \"{}\"".format(word, translation))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestTranslate()
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Your code seems great but I don't quite understand the line ** if vowels and not isEnglishVowel(ch): ** and couldn't make sense of the code arrangement, would you mind explaining? Also, these codes didn't work well on words which end with vowels. for example "spaghetti" gives "spabaghebetti", instead of "spabaghebettibi" [correct translation]. And "adieu" gives "abadieu", rather than "abadieubieu". Thank you! @TylerDonaldson

Comment: An empty string is a "Falsey" value in python. `bool("")` returns False.
Think of `vowels` like a stack. As long as we are encountering vowels in the word, append to the "stack" of characters. When we encounter a non-vowel, "pop" the entire stack onto our translation.
So `if vowels and not isEnglishVowel(ch)` is the check to see if the stack has characters in it, and whether we are ready to "pop" the stack.

Also, you're right, I forgot to account for the end of string. Updated answer to account for that.

Comment: Totally get it now! One last question, I was wondering if you can explain why I have to add another line of `return translation + separator + vowels if vowels` to account for the end string of each word? I'm not quite sure why the lines of code written earlier are not applicable to the end of string. Thanks so much! @TylerDonaldson

Comment: Also, I noticed a difference when I started out with the original characters first by placing it below the line of code `for ch in word`. It ends up with a consonant placed before the separator. For instance, "quick" would be "quicbuik". May I know why is it so? Thank you. @TylerDonaldson

Comment: If the word ends in a vowel, then the for loop will exit before `if vowels and not isEnglishVowel(ch):` is executed again, so we need to perform that check one more time. Doing a `return if` is just a way of simplifying that step.

As for your second question, I'm not sure I understand. Did you move `translation += ch` below `for ch in word`? If so, then you are appending a consonant before checking if the previous characters were vowels.

Comment: I get it now. Thanks a lot! @TylerDonaldson